# How many bytes are in a Location ID from the Instagram API?

Tags: cassandra, int, instagram, instagram-api

I cannot find any decent documentation on the Instagram API about this. I know it returns a number through the API which is usually a 2^32 bit int, but once in a while I will get a number that is 2^64. I want to store these numbers in my Cassandra database, but I am not sure if I should store them as Int(2^32) or BigInt(2^64) or even text.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Instagram API, id's (whether for a User, Media, Location, etc) are returned as strings (as opposed to the float values for "latitude" and "longitude" or the int values returned for fields like count):

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "788029",
    "latitude": 48.858844300000001,
    "longitude": 2.2943506,
    "name": "Eiffel Tower, Paris"
  },
  {
    "id": "545331",
    "latitude": 48.858334059662262,
    "longitude": 2.2943401336669909,
    "name": "Restaurant 58 Tour Eiffel"
  },
  {
    "id": "421930",
    "latitude": 48.858325999999998,
    "longitude": 2.294505,
    "name": "American Library in Paris"
  }]
}
```

It may be best to store them as text in Cassandra.

Comment: I thought location ids are ints though. I guess I was wrong